# find the area of $\triangle ADB$.

Tags: geometry

$ABC$ and $ADE$ are two secants of a circle having radius $3$ units. Point $A$ is at a distance of $5$ units from center. Secants includes an angle of $30^\circ$. If area of $\triangle ACE$ is $10$ square units find the area of  $\triangle ADB$.

Comment: And what have you tried, so far?

Comment: I am not getting from where to start . I  used the formula $0.5*bc\sin{a}$ to get relation between lengths of secants.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Draw the diagram as shown above, let $O$ be the center of the circle, while secants $ABC$ and $ADE$ cut circle $O$ at $B$, $C$, $D$, $E$ respectively, $\angle CAE=30^\circ$. We draw another secant $AFG$ that passes through the center $O$ and cut circle $O$ at $F$, $G$. Therefore, $AF=2$, $AG=8$.

Using Intersecting Secants Theorem and Tangent Secant Theorem, we get $AB\times AC=AD\times AE=AF\times AG=2\times 8=16$. Then we can get $AB\times AC\times AD\times AE=16^2$. Through grouping and some manipulations, we can get $$\left(\frac {1}{2}\sin30^\circ\times AB\times AD\right)\left(\frac {1}{2}\sin30^\circ\times AC\times AE\right)=16$$.

We can see that $\frac{1}{2}\sin30^\circ\times AC\times AE=A_{\triangle ACE}=10$. Hence, $A_{\triangle ADB}=\frac {1}{2}\sin30^\circ \times AB\times AD=1.6$